# Case sensitive eth-addresses with different balances?? How is that?

Tags: transactions, ether, wallets

These are the addresses:

0x7cB57B5A97Eabe94205c07890BE3C1aD31E486A8 
0x7Cb57B5a97EaBe94205c07890bE4C1aD31E456a8 
0x7cB57B5A97eAbe94205C07890BE4c1aD31E486A8 
0x7CB57b5A97eabe94205C07890beaC1aD31E486a8

They all have different transactions/balances on Etherscan. How can that be (as I read everywhere that ETH-addresses are not case-sensitive) and how to avoid when sending a transaction in MEW offline without possibility to make it case sensitive, that it doesn't land in another wallet like in my 4 example addresses?

Thanks in advance for explaining

Answer (score 1):

They are not the same, they are 4 different addresses

0x7cB57B5A97Eabe94205c07890BE**3**C1aD31E486A8  0x7Cb57B5a97EaBe94205c07890bE**4**C1aD31E4**5**6a8  0x7cB57B5A97eAbe94205C07890BE**4**c1aD31E4**8**6A8  0x7CB57b5A97eabe94205C07890be**a**C1aD31E486a8